# How do you let end users customize report columns in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'd like to create a report where users have the ability to choose what columns they want to see from a predetermined list. They should also have other options like applying an aggregate function for footers (average, sum...).

How do I accomplish this with SSRS? (this will be a first report attempt with SSRS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at SSRS Report Builder: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/report-builder.aspx
It's a client app that allows users to write their own reports.